# What happens to the reputation associated with a question if it is removed?

Tags: discussion, support

If a question is flagged to be removed, but it has some reputation associated with it, what happens to that reputation?

If the user has reputation from up votes on the question, will the user loose that reputation?

Does removing questions with down votes return lost reputation to affected users?

Comment: Your question was probably closed for a while before being removed, and the reason for being closed was prominently displayed in the close reason.

Comment: Can you specify which question, or at least what site it was on?

Comment: Any moderator (with the diamond) on the site can find the question in your profile and any user with at least 10k rep can look at given a link if you just want someone to tell you what the close reason was.

Comment: Your question matches most likely one of the types listed in [What Stack Overflow is not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not). Relatively a lot of starters incorrectly treat Stack Overflow as an old fashioned "discussion forum".

Comment: Or, as it's probably [at most 8 days old](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:9qNo-WtlkuwJ:stackoverflow.com/users/1390550/dibya-ranjan+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk): its URL is probably still in your browser's history?

Comment: You have one deleted question, but it had three downvotes and no upvotes. Where does it say you lost 7 reputation?

Comment: +5  16:24  upvote  Is there any online editor to test PHP scripts?

+2  17:05  accept  Is there any online editor to test PHP scripts?

This is the log of my reputation. In FAQ it is stated that if I have any problems then I can discuss in meta. But it seems that all are pressing down vote when a question is asked

Comment: @mmyers
As my log says I had gained +5 and +2 when deleted the post I lost them right?

Comment: Of course you can come to Meta to ask the question, but it doesn't mean the community has to agree with you. See [Are upvotes and downvotes different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). Also, all you need is a single answer upvote and you'll be +3 overall - I guess people just don't see the problem (myself included).

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize you had multiple accounts.

Comment: @mmyers I dnt have multiple account. Bdw is my question on meta not genuine? I have followed almost every guideline provided. Still I have 9 down votes. can anybody tell why? It is just frustrating I got 2 answers for my question and got 9 down votes is this because hitting vote is easier than typing answers?

Comment: You don't *now* because another moderator merged the two accounts. As far as this question's score goes, [voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of useful questions, however the large majority of questions are not suitable for asking on stackoverflow. Read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not), then I'm sure you'll understand why the community chose to close your question. In short, it falls out of the scope of SO. If it is a good question about something technical, there are probably other stackexchange sites that will entertain it.

Answer (score 2):

Removing a question has nothing to with Upvotes and Downvotes. Its still valid to close the question though it is Upvoted/Downvoted.

Check Deleted question link (Page Not Found Page)  it states:

This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation. Please refer to the FAQ for [possible explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) why a question might be removed

From the Deletion [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, 
>      may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.
>
> Over time, closed questions that are not useful as signpoints to other questions 
>      may also be removed, as well as questions which have no significant activity over 
>      a very long period after being asked.